# REST API how to handle incomplete answers

Tags: rest

I am currently developing a REST API with a MongoDB backend and due to access rights clients may look for data where some are accessible and others are forbidden.

For example let's say I wish to have in a single request objects A, B and X from database, but I do not have enough rights to access object X.

I would like my API to answer A, B, and a forbidden status for object X. Any **best-practices** to do it ? What's the resulting request **status code** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user attempts to retrieve a representation of a *single resouce* using its URI and the user doesn't have enough permissions to access such resource, the server is expected to return [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3). Or [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4), in case the server wants to hide the existence of that resource.

On the other hand, in a scenario where a user fetches a representation of a *collection of resources* and not all available resources can be returned due to, for example, lack of permissions, the server should return only the representation of the resources which the user has access to.

---

If you intend to restrict the access to the fields of a resource, you could have different URIs for them and then validate the permissions accordingly.

Consider the following example:

- `/orders/{id}`: Summary of a given order
- `/orders/{id}/items`: Items of a given order
- `/orders/{id}/payment`: Payment details of a given order
- `/orders/{id}/invoice`: Invoice details of a given order
- `/orders/{id}/delivery`: Delivery details of a given order

Comment: How would you go on about the scenario OP mentioned where you have a list of 3 resources, of which 1 is unaccessable to the caller? Do you still show it but give a 403 on it's detail page? Or would you just show 2 results?

Comment: @Ludo21South In a scenario where the API caller is fetching a representation of a collection of resources and not all available resources can be returned due to, for example, lack of permissions, the server should return only the representation of the resources that the user have access to.

Comment: @Ludo21South _"Or would you just show 2 results?"_ That would be the way to go.

Comment: @cassiomolin thanks for this detailed answer, then I guess client-side I'll need to go through returned resources, compare with what I asked and display "forbidden" for those that were not returned by the server ?

Comment: @Jerome Well, it really depensd on your needs and the experience you want to provide to your users. Consider you search for something on Amazon. It will return all products that match your search criteria. Products that don't match the search criteria are not displayed in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *envelopes* for each sub-resource and add a status to each sub-resource.

Assuming that your API return a main resource A which in turn contains two sub-resources B and X. If the caller has no permission to access A, then the API should clearly respond with HTTP/403 as cassiomolin correctly pointed out.

If the caller has full permissions to all resources, a sample response would be (assuming a JSON payload):

```js
    {
    "entityEnvelopeA": {
        "status": "OK",
        "data": {
            "propertyΑ1": "value1",
            "propertyΑ2": "value2"
        }
    },
    "entityEnvelopeΒ": {
        "status": "OK",
        "data": {
            "propertyΒ1": "value1",
            "propertyΒ2": "value2"
        }
    },
    "entityEnvelopeΧ": {
        "status": "OK",
        "data": {
            "propertyΧ1": "value1",
            "propertyΧ2": "value2"
        }
    }
    }
```

If the caller does not have access to sub-resource X, the response would be:

```js
{
    "entityEnvelopeA": {
        "status": "OK",
        "data": {
            "propertyΑ1": "value1",
            "propertyΑ2": "value2"
        }
    },
    "entityEnvelopeΒ": {
        "status": "OK",
        "data": {
            "propertyΒ1": "value1",
            "propertyΒ2": "value2"
        }
    },
    "entityEnvelopeΧ": {
        "status": "FORBIDDEN",
        "data": {}
    }
}
```

If this approach is documented in you API docs, the caller can then examine the `status` field of the envelope before parsing the `data` field.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm nonetheless a bit worried this approach will increase a lot my server payloads since I need to exchange a few data...

Comment: My approach has one (obvious) strength: You can have one endpoint (and one request-response) with versatile payload depending on caller permissions. On the other hand, it's definately not pure REST (sub-resources should be mapped to different URIs as @cassiomolin suggests) and your payloads will be _fatter_ as you point out.